# How to convert a number to a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a number for example 7.

```
number =7
```

How can convert 7 into a list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : `my_list = list(range(1 , num + 1))`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for the range:

```
lst = [item for item in range(1, number + 1)]
```